# Algorithm: Is it possible to sweep(iterate line, column, diagonal and reverse diagonal) a simple array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

Given a simple matrix, not a 2D array, is it possible to iterate diagonal and inverse diagonal without converting to a matrix (2D array)? Or for diagonal, will we always have to convert to 2D matrix?

For example using Java Stream:

Given a simples array:

```java
private static final String[] SIMPLE_ARRAY = new String[] {
            "CTGAGA",
            "CTGAGC",
            "TAGTGT",
            "AGAGGG",
            "CCCETA",
            "TCACTG"
    };
```

**print lines:**

```java
Arrays.stream(SAMPLE_DATA).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output:

```
CTGAGA
CTGAGC
TAGTGT
AGAGGG
CCCETA
TCACTG
```

**print columns:**

```java
IntStream.range(0, SAMPLE_DATA.length).mapToObj(col ->
     Arrays.stream(SAMPLE_DATA).reduce("", (acc, row) -> acc + row.charAt(col))
).forEach(System.out::println);
```

the output:

```
CCTACT
TTAGCC
GGGACA
AATGEC
GGGGTT
ACTGAG
```

**print diagonal:** ?

**print inverse diagonal:** ?

Comment: This question seems tightly linked to Java or at least is language dependent. In some languages this will be super easy, in others harder, and probably there are some where you need to switch to 2D array or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same approach (with streams), you can get the diagonals with:

```java
int n = SIMPLE_ARRAY.length;
// Diagonal 1
IntStream.range(0, n)
         .mapToObj(i -> SIMPLE_ARRAY[i].charAt(i))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
// Diagonal 2
IntStream.range(0, n)
         .mapToObj(i -> SIMPLE_ARRAY[i].charAt(n-1-i))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact your array is 1D or 2D doesn't change much, every 2D index `[i][j]` is convertible to 1D `[i*nCols+j]`, going from 1D index to 2D index is also possible with modulus. Your String is like an array, even in Java, but instead of using `[i]` you have to use `charAt(i)`, so in semantic your `String[]` can be iterated just like a `char[][]`.

The general algorithm to iterate the diagonales is, for loops are inclusives :

```
For d = 0 to min(nRows, nCols) - 1: // min if the matrix is not a square
    i=d
    j=0
    For k = 0 to d: // iterate each element of the d-th diagonale
        // Do something with row i and col j
        i--
        j++
```

That is about the same for reverse diagonales by swapping some indices or use (i, nCols - j -1) instead of (i, j).